# How do I Sort the data returned in JSON format by an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, sorting

I have an AJAX request against a sharepoint API. It returns an array of Files. I am taking these resulting array and adding a series of options to a Select element. I would like to be able to sort the array alphabetically by the Name property. How would I go about doing this? MY current Ajax call is below.Thank you

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("#items").empty();
            jQuery("#items").prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Item-</option>').val('-1');
            jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                jQuery("#items").append('<option value="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '">' + item.Name + '</option>');
            });
            jQuery("#items").val("");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error getItems");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: show us example of return result

Comment: can we see your JSON result please

Comment: Per the Sharepoint API the JSON is in this Format https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileOData

Specifically my two Items follow this format:
"Name":"fileName.docx",
"ServerRelativeUrl":"/Shared Documents/folderName/fileName.docx",

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array in javascript, but can't you get Sharepoint to return an ordered list for you?  Seems like that'd be a useful feature.  Anyway, in javascript:

```
jQuery("#items").prepend('<option value="-1">-Select Item-</option>').val('-1');
var res = data.d.results.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.Name < b.Name) return -1;
    if(a.Name > b.Name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
jQuery.each(res, function (index, item) {
    jQuery("#items").append('<option value="' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '">' + item.Name + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: Ya, I feel kind of stupid now. I'd been so focused on the AJAX query I forgot about the orderby parameter in OData. :-D

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would use somthing like underscore

http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

somthing like this

```
var array = [
    { name: "banana" },
    { name: "carrot" },
    { name: "apple" }
];

var sorted = _.sortBy(array,"name");
```

and pass the data.d.results in the array

Hope it helps

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid any dependencies on external libraries outside Jquery and Sharepoint API

Comment: @Phil Then look at the underscore source and take what you need. It's [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js) and the `sortBy` method starts on line 385.